# create trigger mysql error

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

### Hi, i am trying to create trigger

I have 2 tables

Client_Deatils
C_ID (varchar)

Client_Seq
C_ID (int) auto increment

when a value is added to Client_Details C_ID feild value must be as 'RMP0000001'
Below is what i am using

```
CREATE TRIGGER `RMP_ID` BEFORE INSERT ON `Client_Details`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Client_Seq VALUES (NULL);
SET NEW.C_ID = CONCAT('RMP', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 7, '0'));
```

i am having this error

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER `RMP_ID` BEFORE INSERT ON  `Client_Details` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Client_Seq
VALUES (

NULL
);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: isn't a sequenz field always created as NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update 1***:

> *this is the error it comes up. #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'* –  webdevelopersana

It seems you already have a trigger named `RMP_ID` on the same table and with the same `BEFORE` event. And if you want to modify or re-define it, it has to be *dropped* first.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `RMP_ID`;
```

And then, you can create the trigger with the changes made to its function.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `RMP_ID`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `RMP_ID` BEFORE INSERT ON `Client_Details`
  ...
  ...
```

---

SQL stored procedure or trigger statements are not *single* statements. They contain different blocks of code like *declarations*, and *body*. And each of such declarations, and statements in body must be terminated by a default delimiter `;`, semi-colon. But SQL engine won't accept each of such procedural statements as block statements unless we specify that.

Standard syntax to specify a new `DELIMITER` value. You can use something like `//`, `$$`, etc. And you need to declare this, outside of the procedural statements. This is what you are missing and hence is the error `... at line 3`.

You also need to `END` a procedural block. You are missing it in your code.

You can try the following way:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `RMP_ID` BEFORE INSERT ON `Client_Details`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Client_Seq VALUES (NULL);
    SET NEW.C_ID = CONCAT('RMP', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 7, '0'));  
  END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

***Refer to***: [MySQL: *CREATE TRIGGER Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Hi, I have tried above code this is the error it comes up.    #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'